# stop/terminate timer job if it is taking more than 2hrs in sharepoint (programatically)

Tags: sharepoint

i have created custom timer to read data from sharepoint list and update in another list.i have scheduled job to run daily.it is wroking fine.
but when number of items in list increases job taking more time to execute,so i want to terminate the job if it is taking more than 4hrs,and it has to start again as per schedule.
Please do let me know the way to achieve it.

Comment: AFAIK it is not possible to programatically cancel running timer job.

Answer (score 0):

Control the time of job execution from inside your code which reads and updates data.